# Database schema that manages weekly timesheets

Tags: php, sql, database, database-design

I'm writing this post because I was wondering if somebody could help me to figure out how the best database schema for a simple timesheets app will be.

I can't figure out how to diagram tables that help me to represent weeks of the year, where all the users will log their work week hours.

Cheers, and many thanks for your help! :)

Guillermo

Comment: Your question is to broad and open-ended to "fit" into a single SO question. If you can break it into specific pieces, you'll get better answers.

Comment: Thanks Phillip! I'll do that. Cheers :)

Comment: There is no such thing as "the best for X" unless you very clearly specify what X must be. But then, it's too localized. So your question is either too broad, too subject or too localized, hence not constructive. Please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will share with you a typical model that we use, https://www.dropbox.com/s/3wo9qd2fdpe5yow/timesheet_model.png,  and describe each of the tables:

- useraccount - user information, login etc
- project - the projects that a user can work on
- projectassignment - the assignment of a project to a user, so these are the only projects that the user can see and submit time on
- timesheet - summary information on the timesheet, which week its for, comments etc
- timesheetdetails - a row for each day and each project with the hours worked, this table grows very fast. We also include the projectid foreign key in this table to speed up queries
- approval - a record of approvals made on the timesheet, as there may be a rejection before its approved

[image: Timesheet Data Model]

Hope this helps

The link to the SQL schema is https://www.dropbox.com/s/uadl5689v9j0jcs/timesheet_model_schema.sql (was taking too much time to format to render properly inline)

Comment: @MichaelDurrant how did you do that?

Comment: Please also share the SQL of that shema, it's much work and error-prone to type that from the picture.

Comment: How do you know which dates belong to a certain week?

Comment: In the timesheet table you have a weekendingdate column, so this date will give you which week you are in. If you prefer you can change it to week starting date so that you store the date on which the week starts

Comment: @ssmusoke: what is the diagram drawing tool that you used to draw the diagram above? please give me its name :)
i'm finding a program like that. thank you so much!

Comment: @c633 I am using MySQL Workbench - http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ its free for MySQL and may support other databases for migration purposes