# Timesheet Database schema

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, database-design, schema

There is an old timesheet application being used in my company and i am going to rewrite it in asp.net.

There are other tables which can be linked to new Timesheet table like employee table but my main concern here is the Project and Project_Activity table.

In the current system, there is a one project and a activity table which are linked to the timesheet table seperatly and user has to spend alot of time on selecting activities code they worked on for specific project.

I have came up with the new idea; Project manager will have to fill up a project template and link all the activities code with the one project before starting this project. This way user will have to select the project only and it will automatically bring the associate codes for them.

Here is the logical schema design.

I like to know if this design will work okay? and is it okay to link Project_Activity table with timesheet?

### PROJECT

PK_PROJECT_ID, 
NAME

### PROJECT_ACTIVITIES

PK_PA_ID, 
DESCRIPTION, 
FK_ACTIVITY_ID, 
FK_PROJECT_ID

### ACTIVITIES

PK_ACTIVITY_ID,
DESCRIPTION

### TIME_SHEET

PKID,
EMP_ID,
FK_PK_PA_ID,
DATE,
HOURS

```
    PROJECT -->  PROJECT_ACTIVITIES <-- ACTIVITIES
                    |
                    |
                    |____TIME_SHEET
```

Note: Timesheet table has many other fields which are not a part of this question.

Comment: Shouldn't `FK_PK_PD_ID` be `FK_PK_PA_ID` in the TIME_SHEET table?

Comment: Thanks for the correction, it was a typing mistake.

Comment: Check here for my answer on a model for timesheets - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526625/database-schema-that-manages-weekly-timesheets/10527797#10527797

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming an `Activity` can refer to only one `Project`?

If so, you don't really need the `Project_Activity` table, just put the foreign key to the `Project` table in the `Activity` table.

If an `Activity` can refer to more than one `Project`, then your schema is fine, you have effectively decomposed the many-to-many relationship between `Project` and `Activity`. :)

Comment: PK_ACTIVITY_ID (Activity Code) in the Activities table can be used in different projects.

Comment: Ah okay, well then your design is pretty good :) with the exception of those column names I guess :)

Comment: just want to confirm that PK_PA_ID should be set as a foreign key in the TimeSheet table NOT FK_PROJECT_ID?

Comment: If Timesheets refer to both an activity and a project, then it should be PK_PA_ID as the foreign key. If however Timesheets only relate to projects and there's only one Timesheet per project, then use FK_PROJECT_ID

Comment: There will be more than one user working on one project and they all will be filling up their own timesheets. One timesheet can have multiple projects so on the timesheet page there will be one list for all projects and clicking on the selected project it will show the list of all the activities for that project. First list can be populated from project_activities table (distinct projects) and second list can also be populated from the same table with group by clause. Does it sound okay?

Comment: But there'll only ever be one timesheet for that user on that project yeah? Then using FK_PROJECT_ID is fine and EMP_ID should link to an Employer table if you have one :)

Comment: NO. Actually after every week or at the end of every month all the users have to fill their timesheet showing how much time they have spent on the specific activity. I need to double check with finance that how will they be using timesheet report, is it on project basis or on an individual user basis.

Comment: AH, then yes use PK_PA_ID and link it to PROJECT_ACTIVITY, you should be okay with reporting using that.

Comment: Did you mean link PK_PA_ID to Timesheet?

Comment: Yeah, that way a Timesheet is valid for a given Employee (using EMP_ID) in a given Activity in a given Project on a given Date. That sound right?

Answer (score 0):

In general the schema is OK. I would not use the naming convention you have, as I find it hard to read. No harm in using full words, but that's an aside.

What I would change is the Timesheet table. Do this instead:

```
PKID,
EMP_ID,
FK_PK_PA_ID,
STARTDATE,
ENDDATE
```

This will allow you to easily query who was doing what during a given time more easily. You can also allow records to have a NULL ENDDATE to show an activity currently being worked on.

I would add a trigger to make sure that for the same EMP_ID, a record's STARTDATE and ENDDATE never come between a STARTDATE and ENDDATE of other records (no overlap).

Comment: Hi, I used those naming conventions for readability. Timesheet table has many other fields which are not a part of my questesion here.

Comment: Start and End dates will pull out from Project_Activity table. There is a possibility of two people working on the same activity with in the same project. This timesheet application is quite different than normal ones as One project takes 2-3 years to complete and this project will have 100 activities.

Comment: @user1263981 Note I said *for the same EMP_ID*.